# How to reset localStorage on user side only once?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a react app with redux state which is stored in localStorage

The problem is that data structure has changed and some older users get an error. Need a reset.

If I add `localStorage.clear(`) to the code, it will run every time and there will be no point of using storage it at all.

Is it possible to reset localStorage only once with kind of specific flag passed with deploy? Something like css files which have versions, i.e. .css?412uisqfh9-wq different for deploys

Comment: Load the item and check the data structure.  If it's the old structure then clear it and do whatever you need to do.  Don't go using flags or anything like that as it's easily broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `localStorage.clear()` only once.

What you need to do like below:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("clearStorage") === "<old version number>") {
  localStorage.clear();
  localStorage.setItem("clearStorage", "<new version number>");
}
```

In first run only `if condition` code will execute and after that everytime this condition will be false and will never execute.

Comment: And you can even set the value of a version number of some kind, to track the version it was last cleared

Comment: Looks good. Thank you. With version number this should be a scalable solution

Comment: @SergeyKhmelevskoy I have updated code for version number. Basically approach will be same just added version number instead of boolean.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel agree with you. Added version number instead of boolean to make it more meaningful.